# Collect asynchronous and synchronous data in loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
    var data = [10,21,33,40,50,69];
    var i = 0;          
    var dataSeq = [];
    while(i<data.length){                   
      if(data[i]%2 == 0){                       
          store.findOne({'visibility': true},function(err, data){                               
          dataSeq.push(i)
          i++;                              
          });                           
      }
      else{
       dataSeq.push(i)
       i++;                         
      }
    }
    if(i==data.length-1){
    console.log(dataSeq) // Should Print [1,2,3,4,5]
    return res.status(200).send({  message: 'Task Completed'})    
  }
```

I want to collect data as per loop excecutes. 
I am aware about how to handle async calls in nodejs. But I want the callbacks in sequence.
e.g. Though there is a async call in if condition i want to hault the loop, so that I can push value of i in **dataSeq** and it will result in [1,2,3,4,5] array. I want that sequence because my post operations are dependent on that sequence.

Comment: Why you are using store.findOne?You even does't use data from callback.

Answer (score 0):

I think [asyncjs#eachSeries](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#series) has what you need.

Your code would become something like this:

```
async.each(data, (item, callback) => {
   if(item%2 == 0){                       
          store.findOne({'visibility': true},function(err, data){                               
          dataSeq.push(i)
          i++;                              
          });                           
      }
      else{
       dataSeq.push(i)
       i++;                         
      }
}, (err) => {
  // if any of the callbacks produced an error, err would equal that error
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [async#eachOf](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachOf)

```
var async = require('async');

var data = [10,21,33,40,50,69];
var dataSeq = [];

async.eachOf(data, function(value, key, cb) {
    if (value % 2 == 0) {
        store.findOne({ 'visibility': true })
        .then(function(doc) {
            dataSeq.push(key);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            return cb(err);
        });
    } else {
        cb();
    }
}, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err)
        return res.status(500).send(); # handle the error as you want
    }
    return res.status(200).send({  message: 'Task Completed'})
})
```

Comment: eachOf is still running in parallel as far as I can tell; he said he wants it in series.  That said, he might not be asking for what he really needs, as his example code didn't seem to be dependent on sequential operations.